# When user registers to my app I have to collect: landing url and timestamp of landing url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls, django-sessions

Scenario: User clicks a link on some forum or ad and he lands on: myapp.com/?lg=1231231 ( or myapp.com/landing/bobby - we don't have these yet but I mean this should be global - not just on home route ) we have to store that landing page url and timestamp when he landed in session. User can then browse the site ( unregistered ) - and then he might decide to sign up - and we want that information stored.

How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: you should create a table to store that information. In the request view save a new record whenever that request is called

Comment: yeah, i already updated my user model, but I don't know which view will be called. I mean it must be global,but not for certain view

Comment: you can take a look at middleware as it can be set to be called on every route/views. If you are using session, you can query the session table for each unique user(you can get request.user in middleware)

Comment: I`ll try to make it work with middlewares.Thank you !

Comment: remember not login user, request.user will be returning UnknownUser type. So it's best to save session info to the new table if you see that session don't have a logged in user

Comment: You mean to save that data into new model ? But how could I store that data later from uknown user model to already known user model ?